# How to set a monitor on a method exposed by a module?

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, vuex, es6-modules

In general, how would one add a method defined in an ES6 module to the [Monitor Function](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#monitor-function) feature of Chrome Devtools? As such a method is not defined in the global scope, nor on the `window` object, how to target it for `monitor()`?

Specific to my situation, there is a [Vuex mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) called `setFoo()` defined in `mutations.js`. This file is imported by a module that is then imported by another module. All this is compiled by Webpack. On localhost I have access to source maps, on the production webserver I do not.

How might one monitor invocations of `setFoo()` using DevTool's `monitor()` feature, either with or without a source map?

Comment: "_without a source map?_" - no way. With a source map, Reflect API and parse the DOM tree until you find it in the DOM. Then, invoke the Monitor on what you find.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I'll read up on Reflect. I figured that without the source map there would be no way, but really I only need such functionality in the dev environment so its not a big deal. Thanks.